# Django Error "ImproperlyConfigured: The app label 'fontawesome-free' is not a valid Python identifier."

Tags: django

I am trying to host a website using django and I installed `fontawesome-free[version=5.15.3]` which I used in my project but when I am trying to run `python manage.py makemigrations` I am getting this error `ImproperlyConfigured: The app label 'fontawesome-free' is not a valid Python identifier.` How do I fix this problem?

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/guitarwebsite/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/guitarwebsite/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/guitarwebsite/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/guitarwebsite/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/guitarwebsite/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 255, in create
    return app_config_class(app_name, app_module)
  File "/home/guitarwebsite/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 38, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The app label 'fontawesome-free' is not a valid Python identifier.
```

Answer (score 7):

As @AKX said, this is a known issue for fontawesome-free, fontawesome-pro + django >= 3.2.

This quick-fix helped.
Just before the INSTALLED_APPS add this

```
import sys

sys.modules['fontawesome_free'] = __import__('fontawesome-free')
```

or

```
sys.modules['fontawesome_pro'] = __import__('fontawesome-pro')
```

and then add `"fontawesome_free"` or `"fontawesome_pro"` to your INSTALLED_APPS

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
.........
"fontawesome_free",
#or
"fontawesome_pro",
.........
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Semi fixed as of May 21st. It's fixed with renaming the package to `fontawesomefree`. Here is the [github issue](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/17801#issuecomment-846259423) for more info

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in the `fontawesome-free` Python package, rendering it unusable as a Django app for the time being: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/17801

Comment: Can you tell me what changes should I make to be able to use fontawesome-free, I uninstalled `Django 3.2` installed `Django 3.18` but in my site, now my site is working but  I cant use the icons from fontawesome-free

Comment: If you are in a virtual environment (suppose, .venv), then, go to ```.venv/Lib/site-packages/fontawesome-free/``` and rename it to ```fontawesome_free```, and add it in ```INSTALLED_APPS```. If not using any virtual environment, then ```C:/Users/<USERNAME>/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python38/site-packages/fontawesome-free/``` (with default Python install) and do the same as above. In the Traceback, it seems you are in ```.virtualenvs```, so follow the steps.

Comment: changing /fontawesome-free/ to /fontawesome_free/ in venv worked

Comment: Until you need to install it somewhere else and manually rename files...